# Convert days data in years data in a list

Tags: python, datetime

I want to do a time serie with temperature data from 1850 to 2014. And I have an issue because when I plot the time series the start is 0 and it corresponds to day 1 of January 1850 and it stops day 60 230 with the 31 December of 2014.

I try to do a loop to create a new list with the time in month-years but it didn't succeed, and to create the plot with this new list and my initial temperature list.
This is the kind of loop that I tested :

```
days = list(range(1,365+1))
years = []
y = 1850
years.append(y)

while y<2015:
    for i in days:
        years.append(y+i)
    y = y+1
del years [-1]

dsetyears = Dataset(years)
```

I also try with the tool called "datetime" but it didn't work also (maybe this tool is better because it will take into account the bissextile years...).

```
day_number = "0"
year = "1850"
res = datetime.strptime(year + "-" + day_number, "%Y-%j").strftime("%m-%d-%Y")
```

If anyone has a clue or a lead I can look into I'm interested.
Thanks by advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that using `datetime` module. Let's declare starting and ending date.

```
import datetime

dates = []

starting_date = datetime.datetime(1850, 1, 1)
ending_date = datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 1)
```

Then we can create a while loop and check if the ending date is greater or equal to starting date and add 1-day using `timedelta` function for every iteration. before iteration, we will append the formatted date as a string to the `dates` list.

```
while starting_date <= ending_date:

    dates.append(starting_date.strftime("%m-%d-%Y"))
    starting_date += datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```

Comment: Thanks ! I replace my "time" list by this new "dates" list and I think it will be good, my last issue is that I don't have temperature data for each days, how can I do to attribute a date only when we have a temperature ? Can I just say to Python to ignore when there isn't data ?

Comment: @Berenice how is the temperature connected to this list? I mean do you create a dictionary or what? It would be helpful if you can attach me a snippet of your code with temperature and I will help you

Comment: The data come from a NetCDF file, I extract the area that I want studied, I do not have temperature data for each days because it comes from real measurement.

Comment: In reality I don't have the same step between each value so I can't initialized a step, maybe it will be easier to just convert the "time" list in month and years ?

Comment: @Berenice if you think it will be easier, there is a code to do so.
`splitted = [x.split('-') for x in dates] days = [x[0] for x in splitted] months = [x[1] for x in splitted] years = [x[2] for x in splitted]`